# They kill as many people as not: what words are omitted?

Tags: comparative-constructions, as

I found the following sentence:

> they kill as many people as not.

In this case, they account for success and fame in publication.

Comment: There are similar constructions that adds intensity. *as temporal or manner expression as not*. This adds intensity to *temporal or manner expressions*. But your sentence sounds a bit odd. Where from did you get this sentence?

Answer (score 8):

In this kind of sentence, "as not" means "The verb takes place or doesn't take place about equally as often."

> They kill as many people as (they do) not (kill).

A similar if not exactly the same omission might be this:

> — "Don't worry, Anne, you don't have to visit Mrs. Lynne if you don't want to."
>   
> — "Oh, I'd just as soon see her as not!"

That is,

> — "I'd be just as happy to see her as not (to see her)!"

Once we know this, the question is, what's the pragmatic value of saying "as not" in these sentences? Interestingly enough, it seems to reinforce the *positive* sense of the verb.

> They kill as many people as not.
>   
>  (You'd think they wouldn't kill very many people, but they kill just as many as they spare.)
>
> I'd just as soon see her as not.
>   
>  (You'd think I would want to avoid her, but I would be just as happy to see her.)

Answer (score 3):

1. **STRUCTURE:**

The expression in question has the structure like this:

> as X as not

He X can be realized by an Adverb Phrase (AdvP) or an Adjective Phrase (AdjP).

2. **FUNCTION:**

   - *(i) Adjunct:*

**A.** Manner Adjunct -

> she'll cut your throat as quick(ly) as not.
>
> It's a nice story, and we can choose to belive it as easily as not.

**B.** Temporal Adjunct -

> As often as not the results are dumb.

- *(ii) Complement:*

> It's as possible as not.

3. **SEMANTICS:**

No matter what function that expression has in a sentence, or by what it's realized, semantically it's used as an intensifier.

> It's as possible as not. (*it's very much possible.*)
>
> she will cut your throad as quick(ly) as not. (*she will cut your throat very quick(ly)*)
>
> It's a nice story, and we choose to belive it as easily as not (we choose to believe it too easily)

4. **USAGE:**

This is not a very common expression (except some set phrases like *as like(ly) as not* or *as often as not*). As a complement it's even rarer.

5. **GRAMMATICAL ANALYSIS:**

> as X as not ==> as X as (something is) not.

So there is an ellipsis.

> It's as possible as not. ==> It's as possible as (it is) not.

In this sentence -

> I will see him as soon as not.

This means I will see him very soon. There is a more common expression *I will see him as soon as 2 hours*.

> I will see him as soon as [I will not see him].

say, it takes 2 hours to reach him. So I will not see him for this 2 hours. And I can only see him after 2 hours. If we add urgency we say it this way *as soon as 2 hours*.

---

OP's sentence is:

> They kill as many people as not.

It's common to say *as many people as 12* etc.

But this sentence with *as many people as not* is very rare and odd. And you wouldn't hear people say it generally. Though it's grammatical and understandable.